# How to strongly type a view with 2 classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to strongly type a view with 2 tables?
I mean if I want to display a view that contains data coming from 2 tables and then how do I 
stongly type a view with my data that comes from 2 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that directly but you can create a ViewModel class with two properties on it that hold references to your table. You strongly type the View against that ViewModel class.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModelTables
{
   public MyTable customer {get; set;}
   public MyOtherTable MyOtherTable {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ViewModelTables>" %>

<% foreach(var tab1Item in Model.customer)
   { %>
   // render here what ever you want to render
   <%: Html.TextboxFor(name => tab1Item.Name) %>
<% } %>

<% foreach(var tab2Item in Model.MyOtherTable)
   { %>
   // render here what ever you want to render
<% } %>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyDoubleTables()
{
   var my2Tab = new ViewModelTables();

   var tab1 = GetTable1(); // whatever you need to do 
   var tab2 = GetTable2(); // whatever you need to do 

   my2Tab.MyTable = tab1;
   my2Tab.MyOtherTable = tab2;

   return View(my2tab);
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: @rene. Is your example right? I am getting errors in my application.
I am not able to declare Mytable and Myothertable

Comment: Replace those types with the ones you actually want to use

Comment: @sly_Chandan i didn't compile it nor does it fits smoothly in your situation. I corrected the ViewModel class becuase that didn't had the propertynames. You need to adapt this to your own needs.

Comment: <% foreach(var tab1Item in Model.customer)
Line 13:    { %>
Line 14:    // render here what ever you want to render

I get an error on the first line.


CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModelTables>' does not contain a definition for 'customer' and no extension method 'customer' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.ViewModelTables>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to have a property named customer in the ViewModel class if you do it this way

Comment: Hats off to You!! ...I managed to get what I wanted to do but there is more to it I guess. I will learn. Thanks anyways. Stackoverflow ROX!

Comment: @Rene.......I want to create a generic list of my table Order in my ViewModelTables. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Something along thr line of List<Order>? Maybe ask a new question, showing what you have now and ask about the order. Make sure to include how your "order" table is currently retreived/constructed.